# Focus handling in ResponsivePopover / Dialog / Popover

Tags: sapui5

I struggle to understand the automatic focus handling in SAPUI5 and how to change its default behavior:

Let's say I have a ResponsivePopover with a SearchField in it. When I open the popover, the SearchField gets focused automatically.

However when there is an `<endButton>` aggregation with a Button in it, it gets the focus instead.

Try it out here: [JSbin: Focus in ResponsivePopover](http://jsbin.com/fuzivik/9/edit?html,js,output)

```js
function showPopover(oEvent) {
  var oRespPopover = new ResponsivePopover({
    showHeader: true,
    title: "title",
    content: [
      new SearchField(),
      // ...
    ],
    /*
    endButton: new sap.m.Button({
      text: 'close',
      press: function(oEvent) {
        oRespPopover.close();
      }
    }),
    */
    afterClose: function(oEvent) {
      oEvent.getSource().destroy();
    }
  });
  oRespPopover.openBy(oBtn);
};
```

### General question

Where is defined which Control gets the focus and how can I change this behavior? 
I checked the [Implementing Focus Handling documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/91f19f036f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070) on this topic, but did not manage to achieve anything.

### My specific case

How can I prevent that the SearchField gets the focus (because that triggers the keyboard on mobile devices), without having an EndButton aggregation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the target focus control has a stable ID, you can assign that ID to the [`initialFocus`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ResponsivePopover/associations) association of the `sap.m.ResponsivePopover`, `sap.m.Dialog`, or `sap.m.Popover` so that the target control gets focused even if there are buttons in the `end`/`beginButton` aggregation.

> Focus on the popover is set in the sequence of `beginButton` and `endButton`, when available. But if a control other than these two buttons needs to get the focus, set the `initialFocus` with the control which should be focused on. <sup>[src](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.Popover/associations)</sup>

**In XML:**

```xml
<ResponsivePopover initialFocus="myFocusableControl"><!--Same for Dialog, Popover, ...-->
  <content>
    <SomeFocusableControl id="myFocusableControl" />
  </content>
</ResponsivePopover>
```

**Or in JS (Controller):**

```js
new ResponsivePopover({ // Same for Dialog, Popover, ...
  initialFocus: this.getView().createId("myFocusableControl"),
  content: [
    new SomeFocusableControl({
      id: this.getView().createId("myFocusableControl"),
    }),
  ],
  // ...
});
```

---

**Note:** For mobile devices, initial focus does not trigger opening the on-screen keyboard.

> Setting `initialFocus` to input controls doesn't open the On-Screen keyboard on mobile device as, due to browser limitation, the On-Screen keyboard can't be opened with JavaScript code. The opening of On-Screen keyboard **must be triggered by real user** action. <sup>[src](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.Dialog/associations)</sup>