# Focus on Input Field Within Dialog

Tags: sapui5

I have an input field along with two other controls in a dialog box. How to ensure that the moment the dialog box opens, the cursor is on the input field (`id="P1"`)?

#### XML View

```xml
<Dialog id="ABC">
  <!-- ... -->
  <Input id="P1" value="{order>/OrderNo}" />
  <!-- ... -->
</Dialog>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Focus handling in ResponsivePopover / Dialog / Popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46547481/focus-handling-in-responsivepopover-dialog-popover)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a association in the dialog control called

> initialFocus

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.54.8/#/api/sap.m.Dialog/associations

In case you don't know about associations:

It is a basic relation between two controls. In the 1 to 1 relation that is needed in your example the `id` of the "lesser" control is stored in the "higher". (not shure how to descripe that the right way)

In following example the `label` and its `input` field are associated that way. The "lesser" controls `id` (`input`) is stored in the label that represents it:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.54.8/#/sample/sap.m.sample.Label/code

SAPs explanation:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.54.8/#/topic/5ee3be4727864bb08b991414e0428e38

In your exaple the xml would look smth like:

```
<Dialog id="ABC" initialFocus="P1"..... >
.
.
.
    <Input id="P1" ... />
.
.
.
```

Comment: Thank you Erch, I realised already that I had to use  control ID, but I was using the wrong control ID, so it never worked, and I thought I had to do something more. So asked here again.  It is working fine now.